# Как отловить момент, когда заполнение ItemsControl завершено?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть `ItemsControl`. У него есть свойство `ItemsSource`, которое может изменяться по ходу работы программы. Как мне ловить момент, когда все элементы загрузились? Событие `Loaded` срабатывает всего один раз, при запуске, а мне надо ловить каждый раз, когда меняется источник ресурсов.

Дополнения к вопросу:

- В качестве `ItemsControl` выступает `TreeView`
- Я подписываюсь на событие `Loaded` каждого итема дерева
- Нужное мне событие должно сработать после того, как все элементы прогрузились, а `AddValueChanged` срабатывает раньше

Comment: Пишите сразу, зачем оно вам понадобилось.

Comment: @Discord, потому что на форме есть 2 слоя. Верхний слой отрисовывается поверх нижнего по контрольным точкам нижнего. А контрольные точки появляются только после полной инициализации слоя.

Answer (score 4):

Положим, что `ItemsSource` привязан к `ObservableCollection`, экземпляр которой не изменяется. Подпишитесь на изменения коллекции, к которой привязан `ItemsSource`. Когда коллекция изменяется, вызывайте `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` с приоритетом `Loaded`. Если экземпляр меняется, то подпишитесь ещё и на изменения `ItemsSource` с помощью `DependencyPropertyDescriptor.AddValueCHanged`.

Comment: Я уже попробовал через `AddValueCHanged`. Срабатывает слишком рано.

Comment: Добавил кое что к вопросу

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29355/itemscontrol-

Comment: @iRumba Вы не можете отловить момент, когда абсолютно все элементы прогрузились. В зависимости от глубины дерева, виртуализации и прочего это может вообще никогда не произойти. И научитесь наконец сразу вставлять в вопрос всю необходимую информацию: не только урезанную мелкую задачку, но и минимальный полноценный пример, когда это нужно. Список и дерево — это две большие разницы, что называется, несмотря на общего предка.

Comment: Дерево прогружается полностью, потому что это граф, который по дефолту Expanded

Comment: какую полную информацию я должен выставить? Я выставил все, что посчитал нужным. Я ведь не знаю наверняка что может потребоваться. Вот оказалось, что есть разница, какого типа источник данных. Я уточнил. Для этого здесь и созданы комментарии. Если бы я смог сразу собрать всю информацию, которая потребуется для ответа, скорее всего ответ я бы нашел сам. Складывать 2 + 2 я умею

Comment: wpf выполняет за меня часть работы, заполняя дерево из источника данных. Я указал схему и источник. Вот заполняет он, заполняет поочередно, выполняя при этом события Loaded каждого итема. А потом, раз, и закончил работать. неужели при этом wpf не вернет мне никакого сигнала? А что, если бы я делал какой то индикатор инициализации? На чем бы он основывался?

Comment: В каком вообще порядке это все выполняется? Вот изменился источник данных, дерево начинает перестраиваться. Из шаблона рисуется корневой итем. У него есть событие `Loaded`. Оно выполняется сразу, перед инициализацией дочерних элементов? Или параллельно? Или вообще в самом конце после инициализации всех элементов? Я не могу найти эту информацию самостоятельно. В документации и литературе она как то кусками расположена. Либо очень поверхностно и я не могу собрать из этого целую каритну. Создается впечатление, что сами разработчики wpf не знают наверняка, как работает эта махина )